# How include knex bindings in the error object when SQL fails at the db?

Tags: knex.js

When the SQL fails due to "NOT NULL" constraint, the error is thrown and error includes the actual SQL statement with :1, :2 bindings.

How to get actual binding values( like :1 corresponds to email address and :2 corresponds key)?

Here is an example:

```
    Knex("user")
    .insert(userRec)
    .then(count => {
        return count;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message)
        return (err);
    }
```

err.message displays the below:

Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("USER"."NAME")
insert into "USER" ("NAME", "EMAIL") values (:1, :2) - ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("S"."USER"."NAME")

I need to display the actual values of :1 and :2 bind variables in the error message.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but the Knex people certainly make it easy!

See https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2295 for the backstory, but the core idea is that you can use Knex's (undocumented) event listener before you query, to say "when an error happens, log the query's bindings".  To modify your example:

```
 knex("user")
   .on('query-error', function (error, { bindings }) {
      console.log(`Bindings: ${bindings}`);
    })
  .insert(userRec)
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message)
      return (err);
  }
```

With that code, you'll see your bindings before the error in the logs.  For instance, if you mess up (like I did recently) and pass a
Promise in to your Knex insert, you'll get error output like:

```
Bindings: 29,,,,[object Promise],false,,Test2, 2
error: insert into "some_table" ... rest of error message
```